# Scraping LinkedIn

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape LinkedIn for particular search results. I am able to log in and get the HTML code of the page using selenium. However, I am getting only first 5 records of every page.
I am enclosing the code script.
I tried using beautiful soup but it is not working.
url for scraping:https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=director%20supply%20chain&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&page=1

```
names=[]


for link in search_urls:

    url = link
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    index= html.find("<span class=\"name actor-name\"")

    html2=html[index:]
    while html2.find("<span class=\"name actor-name\"") != -1:

        index=html2.find("<span class=\"name actor-name\"")
        remaining=html2[index:]

        start=remaining.find(">")

        end=remaining.find("</")


        names.append(remaining[start+1:end])

        remaining=remaining[end:]

        index=remaining.find("</span>")
        html2=remaining[index:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it use scroll event to get more results from ajax, use `.location_once_scrolled_into_view` to scroll.

```
names=[]

for link in search_urls:
    url = link
    driver.get(url)
    hasScroll = True
    while hasScroll:
        try:
            hasScroll = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-result__occlusion-hint')
            hasScroll.location_once_scrolled_into_view
            # wait ajax request, increase if needed
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            break

    # no more scrollable content, extract it
    actorNames = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.name.actor-name')
    names = [name.text for name in actorNames]
```

Comment: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: I am getting the above error at line actorNames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name actor-name')

Comment: sorry, it should be `find_element_by_css_selector` see above

Comment: Now the eroor is AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_selector'

Comment: my bad :D missing `s` it should be `find_elements_by_css_selector`

Comment: Sorry, pls ignore the above comment, the error is NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"name actor-name"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: The code executed but the array' names' is having zero elements

Comment: Now i am able to get 7 records of the 10 records on the page

Comment: change selector to `.actor-name`

Comment: I did changed and now I am getting only 7 records per page

Comment: Also, could you please let me know how can I get designation as well along with name ?

Comment: strange I get 10 results. for pagination create new post I will try to help